# Can't run flutter application on windows

Tags: flutter

Can't run Flutter app on Windows
error:

```
C: \ Program Files (x86) \ Microsoft Visual Studio \ 2019 \ Community \ MSBuild \ Microsoft \ VC \ v160 \ Microsoft.CppCommon.targets (240.5): error MSB8066: custom build for "C: \ Users \ koval \ Google Drive \ usu \ build \ windows \ CMakeFiles \ 001f907f757f26e1d0e8ea253f012e02 \ flutter_windows.dll.rule; C: \ Users \ koval \ Google Drive \ usu \ build \ windows \ CMakeFiles \ 3fd8b3cb8ccas370a7ca36fab975 "code C: \ Users \ koval \ Google Drive \ usu \ build \ windows \ flutter \ flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
Exception: Build process failed.
```

What is the problem?

Flutter doctor:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, 2.0.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.21313.1000], locale en-GB)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.9.0)
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.53.1)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
```

launched by clicking green button in Android Studio

Comment: Can you provide the result of your `flutter doctor` and which command you tried to run please.

Comment: @GuillaumeRoux Wait

Comment: @GuillaumeRoux added information